# malloc size modified after changing stored value?

Tags: c++, malloc

I have a program that uses malloc to allocate a void-typed space for my program
the value I pass to malloc is 1 so it should allocate 1 byte.

Now I cast the pointer to int and modify it's value to int (eg, 280).
I am pretty sure that an int needs 4 bytes of memory to be stored, and I know for a fact that
280 is represented by at least 2 bytes

My expectations are that since I only have a pointer of 1 byte size, the whole integer
wouldn't fit in that space, I thought that there would be an error or something (there were none)
Then I thought that the integer was stored to RAM starting from the pointer start and exceeding the allocated memory, and since I would print the pointer of the allocated memory

I should get a value that represents the whole 1st byte of the number (in this case: 24)

BUT:

When I try to print the value of the pointer the value is still 280

Now what I am thinking is that somehow the program auto-allocates more size for that pointer

But I also think that's weird, could anyone explain what is happening here?

I would also like to know how to store ONLY the 1st byte of 280.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  void* p = malloc(1); // This should allocate 1 byte
  *(int*)p = 280; // This should cast p to an integer, dereference it and set value to 280
  std::cout << *(int*)p << std::endl; // This prints 280 but I think it should print 24
  free(p);
}
```

The above is a pseudo-code that should do what a class I made does, instead of sending the whole class I just replaced the constructor, operator=, destructor to their actual code

**EDIT**:

I am using mingw32-g++ to compile the application

gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)

Comment: Not allocating sufficient memory results in _undefined behavior_, meaning that you have no guarantees whatsoever what will happen. It may or may not result in an error, produce the "expected" outcome or produce non-sense. Aside from that, using `malloc` and `free` in C++ in this way is almost always wrong and likely to cause undefined behavior by itself depending on the type that is used. What is the reason for using `malloc` here in the first place?

Comment: `malloc` typically has a certain granularity, so in reality the requested size is rounded up to the nearest (typically) 4-byte boundary. In either case, it is _your_ responsibility to not write beyond the requested size - it is not enforced.

Comment: @user17732522 This is an exercise to learn more about memory allocation

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So even if I request 1 byte, it will allocate 4? And I need to keep track of what I'm writing to that memory space so it is within boundaries?

Comment: @user18812922 it can allocate what it needs to, it could allocate precisely 1 byte or it could allocate 4k. Regardless the standard only lets you *access* 1 byte legally. Touching anything else in the allocation is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user18812922 So do you want to learn about the implementation of `malloc` on your platform or what exactly is the goal? In terms of _using_ `malloc`, undefined behavior is undefined behavior and there isn't much more to say.

Comment: @user17732522 As I said this is an exercise, 1 of my professors said that it would be a good practice to learn how it works, and I also want to find out how older programs (written in C) use malloc (I know I should probably use C, but anyway)

Comment: @user18812922 OK, yes, in C using `malloc`/`free` is appropriate, but in C++ it isn't. Anyhow, regarding the size of the allocation, allocating too little for the type will result in undefined behavior in both languages.

Comment: @user17732522 That's why I asked what is happening, because I thought it will write after the pointer's boundaries but I couldn't answer why it printed the 280's whole number. (but I thought I was getting out of boundaries)

Comment: In addition to the UB, compilers are also smarter than we might think. For example, on my machine `*(int*)p = 280; std::cout << *(int*)p:` is optimized into `std::cout << 280;`. No need to read back what you just wrote!

Comment: @BoP I appreciate the information, I didn't actually know it. The reason I made it read back and print was just to see the output, I then did more things with it like arithmetic operations and then storing a different typed-value like chars and bools. But anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malloc only allocates one byte but has no mechanism to avoid that you write on other memory addresses, by writing 4 bytes in the address of p you write the allocalted byte + 3 other consecutive bytes.
After that when you deference the pointer you read 4 bytes that are the same ones you just wrote.
What you are doing is writing and reading on memory that the program probably isn't using, but this is undefined behaviour and you shouldn't ever do it as it can lead to segmentation faults.

Comment: so to get the number 24 out of the 280, I should manually write each bit of the first byte to that address? Would that avoid undefined behavior if I then manually read and store the 1st byte to another int typed variable?

Comment: @user18812922 or you could do `int firstbyte = input & 0xFF;`

Comment: @Mgetz The reason I cannot do this is because I should be able to store different types to that address later (not only ints), that's the reason I use 1 byte after all, I want to store only the 1st byte of some given types